# What's the meaning of expression "talismán de piel" in a song?

Tags: expresiones, letras-de-canciones

There's this famous Spanish song called "El Talisman", by Rosana.

The lyrics start with:

> El **talismán de tu piel** me ha dicho
>   Que soy la reina de tus caprichos
>   Yo soy el as de los corazones
>   Que se pasean en tus tentaciones
>   El talismán de tu piel me cuenta
>   Que en tu montura caerán las riendas

I can't figure out what "talismán de tu piel" means in this context. The literal translation - "talisman of your skin" - is not very enlightening.

Comment: Since [_talismán_](https://dle.rae.es/?id=YzyWncZ) is some object with some magical powers, I assume it is a poetic way to say "your dear skin", that is, "you" in a probable erotic sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, *el talismán de tu piel* might be translated as *the talisman that your skin is* or even *your talisman skin*, meaning *your skin, which is a talisman, has told me...*. Of course, here it has a poetic sense, but you can use this construction even in quite vulgar contexts:

> El idiota de mi hermano me ha roto el ordenador --> My idiot brother (my brother, who is an idiot,) broke my computer

Be aware that, in this construction, the second noun must have a modifier (an article or a posesive, usually). *Talismán de piel*, as the question says, would mean *skin talisman* (i.e. a talisman made of skin), which is quite different.

Answer (score 1):

A talisman (or *talismán*) is something that gives me good luck or special protection.  In a literal way a lock of hair could be used as a talisman.  Here, we are not going to hold onto a piece of skin the way we might hold onto a lock of hair, but in poetry we are allowed to be a little bit less technically correct.  I think the poet is using "talisman" as a less tangible thing -- more of a concept -- than one usually does.